# C# saving multiple files with different names loop

Tags: c#, image, file, charts

I'm trying to make loop for creating charts from datagridview with multiple columns. I have my code to create charts in this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= columnCount; i++)
```

Now at the end of program im saving my chart as image:

```
chart1.SaveImage("chart1.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

But i'm in loop so what i want is to make name of every chart to look like this pseudo thing:

```
chart1.SaveImage("chart1"+"[i]"+".png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

like change name with every new chart: chart1.png chart2.png chart3.png...

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is a problem here ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use interpolated string:

```
for (i = 0; i <= columnCount; i++)
    chart[i].SaveImage($"chart{i}.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple concatenation should work:

```
chart[i].SaveImage("chart" + i + ".png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

It's equivalent to a call to [`String.Concat(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx).

Comment: Hi @LJohnson if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the concatenation use like this:

```
string fileName = String.Format("chart[{0}].png",i);
chart[i].SaveImage(fileName, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```